# Most Efficient Filter Location of Subquery (GROUP BY) In JOIN

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, join, filter

```
SELECT * FROM foo f
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT bar_id, MAX(revision_id) FROM bar b
    GROUP BY bar_id
) t ON t.bar_id = f.bar_id
```

OK, so hears the question: lets say there are in the millions of records in these tables and I want the query to be as efficient as possible.

Is MySQL going to pull all of the records for the bar table and then filter them on the ON statement at the join level instead of inside the sub query? Or is there a way to filter the items inside the sub query with just SQL by itself before the JOIN filter?

It seems querying all of the records to filter them would be inefficient and I have not thought of a way yet to get around this.

I have tried this but the subquery cannot see the foo table:

```
SELECT * FROM foo f
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT bar_id, MAX(revision_id) FROM bar b
    WHERE b.bar_id = f.bar_id
    GROUP BY bar_id
) t ON t.bar_id = f.bar_id
```

Is there a way to pass the id down to the subquery, I just like to do things the optimal way, and I'm sure there is a way to do this.

Thanks for all responses.

Comment: you can add indexes to improve the performance

Comment: can you also post an explain and show create table  and number of records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is MySQL going to pull all of the records for the bar table and then filter them on the `ON` statement at the join level instead of inside the sub query?

Most likely, it will do the subquery in full before doing the join. If you want to know for sure, look at the execution plan as `EXPLAIN` shows it.

There is a special case where this approach might even be beneficial: if `bar` is large but `bar_id` takes only few values, and if many rows from `foo` reference these same few `bar_id` values, then choosing the maximal revision for each id up front, before joining them to the `foo` rows, might be good.

> Or is there a way to filter the items inside the sub query with just SQL by itself before the `JOIN` filter?

You can avoid the subquery altogether:

```sql
SELECT f.*, MAX(b.revison_id)
FROM foo f INNER JOIN bar b ON b.bar_id = f.bar_id
GROUP BY f.foo_id
```

I'm assuming that each row in `foo` can be uniquely identified by its `foo_id`; you might have to use multiple columns there, or introduce new keys. The result will therefore also contain one row for every row in `foo`, but only if there is also at least one matching row in `bar`. All the rows in `bar` will be aggregated in that `MAX` call, so you get the maximal `revision_id` from these.

> I have tried this but the subquery cannot see the foo table: […]

A good thing this does not work. The closes thing that *would*  work would be some dependent query, which would have to be executed repeatedly, once for every foo row. Which is a performance killer. If in doubt, try both on your real data and simply compare execution times for a sufficiently large number of executions.

Conclusion: Try to avoid subquerys where possible, and try even harder to avoid dependent subqueries.

Comment: Are you sure the code above will run? SQL standards say each column not part of an aggregate function should be included into the `GROUP BY` clause and columns from the `foo` table are not...

Comment: MySQL is less strict about that part of the spec, and allows ungrouped columns by choosing an arbitrary one. But your question raises a good point: I implicitely assumed that every row in bar would match at most one row in foo, which probably was an invalid assumption. Therefore, you'd rather group by some key which uniquely identifies foo rows. Do you have a `foo_id`? I'll use that in my answer.